# Exponential function in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("Col3",
when(col("Col2")=="Tree",exp(-50*col("Col1"))))
```

Error Message:
TypeError: attribute of type 'Column' is not callable

How to use exponential function on a column?
I need to calculate exponential function with and without a column (1 - exp(-50))

Answer (score 0):

Works well for me. I do not see any issues.

Might be your `col1` is `string` , You ll need to convert them to `float`.

## String to Float Conversion -

```
sparkDF.withColumn('col1',F.col('col1').cast(DoubleType()))
```

```
sample_col1_values = list(map(float,"""5.000001911924775E-4| |6.999999313363147E-4| |7.000007191664842E-4| |8.999982752162926E-4| |9.000003378596106E-4
        | |4.000000531183995E-4| |3.000005084098568E-4| |2.999999164269311E-4| |2.999999999999999E-4""".split("| |")))

sample_col2_values = ['Tree','Tree','Tree','Root','Root','Root','Leaf','Leaf','Leaf']


input_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(sample_col1_values,sample_col2_values)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['col1','col2'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("col3",
                            F.when(F.col("col2")=="Tree"
                           ,F.exp(-50*F.col("col1")))
                    )

sparkDF.show()
+--------------------+----+------------------+
|                col1|col2|              col3|
+--------------------+----+------------------+
|5.000001911924776E-4|Tree|0.9753099027047368|
|6.999999313363147E-4|Tree|0.9656054195726678|
|7.000007191664842E-4|Tree|0.9656053815360145|
|8.999982752162926E-4|Root|              null|
|9.000003378596106E-4|Root|              null|
|4.000000531183995E-4|Root|              null|
|3.000005084098568E-4|Leaf|              null|
|2.999999164269311E-4|Leaf|              null|
|2.999999999999999E-4|Leaf|              null|
+--------------------+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Col2 value sample : 5.000001911924775E-4|
|6.999999313363147E-4|
|7.000007191664842E-4|
|8.999982752162926E-4|
|9.000003378596106E-4|
|4.000000531183995E-4|
|3.000005084098568E-4|
|2.999999164269311E-4|
|2.999999999999999E-4|

Comment: Is there a need to create dataframe explicity? I am reading from a file and then performing calc on it for ex : df = read.csv..()

Comment: Updated the answer. Sample data helps , as I do not have the file you posses.

Comment: Sample data: Col1 Col2
0.0003000001911924770000 Tree
0.0007999999313363140000 Tree 0.0003000001283354100000 Root
0.0007999995171267490000 Root

Comment: df1 = df.withColumn("Col3",
when(col("Col2")=="Tree",exp(1")))) - works but df1 = df.withColumn("Col3",
when(col("Col2")=="Tree",exp(-50*col("Col1")))) doesnt..
TypeError: attribute of type 'Column' is not callable......col1 is already type double

Comment: Below code worked
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
df1 = df.withColumn("Col3",
when(F.col("Col2")=="Tree",F.exp(-50*F.col("Col1"))))....... can u explain what changed

Comment: Query: On a column F.exp works and on a num exp works.....can u explain how?